# Removing an element with `vec.erase(find(...) )` if `find` should start searching in reverese order

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector of unique(!) elements and want to remove one, with a certain value. It's also very likely that this element will be near the end of the vector. Hence I want to start looking for this element from the end.

I thought this should work, however it does not.

```
vec.erase( find(crbegin(vec), crend(vec), value) ); //does not work
```

The compiler sais (shorten):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<unsigned int>::erase(std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> > >)'

and also

note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> > >' to 'std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> >}'
```

If I don't use reverse iterators, it works (hence the compiler note):

```
vec.erase( find(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), value) ); //works
```

How can I tell find that it should start searching for `value` from the end?

edit: I know, that the vector contains the searched element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't tell the `vector` to erase an element with some kind of iterator it doesn't know about. You need to turn the reverse iterator back into a `std::vector::iterator`. Do this with [`std::reverse_iterator::base()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base). However, this would give you an off-by-one error, since reverse iterators have to do some shifting to account for not having an "end" iterator at the beginning of the range. Use [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) to account for this:

```
vec.erase(std::prev(find(crbegin(vec), crend(vec), value).base()));
```

Bear in mind that this assumes that the element is found, however. Your code already does this and your edit says you assume this deliberately, so I'm not introducing a new problem, but in reality you should check the element is found before trying to erase it. Something like (untested):

```
auto foundCRIt = std::find(std::crbegin(vec), std::crend(vec), value);
if (foundCRIt == std::crend(vec)) {
    std::cerr << "Not found!\n";
    return;
}
vec.erase(std::prev(foundCRIt.base()));
```

Comment: Ah, true. I thought the base iterator was an iterator to the same element that the reverse iterator would dereference to. Now that I think about it, it makes sense that that cannot be possible, since you would want to be able to access all the original iterators through `base()`. Thanks for that. I have corrected my answer.